# how to make edit text multi style in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC9RL.jpg)

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int lineEndIndex = edtMenu.getText().toString().indexOf("\n");
            int firstLineLength;
            if (lineEndIndex == -1) {
                firstLineLength = edtMenu.getText().toString().length();
                Log.e("line First", "Hello" + firstLineLength);
            } else {
                firstLineLength = lineEndIndex;
            }
        }
```

I am Find First Line Char from If condition but now i want to find charter of new line after space. how can i do it?

Comment: Please Follow Image in case you can't understand

There is Three Title with different color and i use line edit text for that.

Answer (score 0):

To select any part of text use [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html):

```
String text2 = text + CepVizyon.getPhoneCode() + "\n\n"
            + getText(R.string.currentversion) + CepVizyon.getLicenseText();

Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(text2);

spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), text.length(), (text + CepVizyon.getPhoneCode()).length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

myTextView.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

You can also format your TextView using `html` markup like below:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text + "<font color=white>" + CepVizyon.getPhoneCode() + "</font><br><br>"
            + getText(R.string.currentversion) + CepVizyon.getLicenseText()));
```

or instead of `TextView` use `WebView` and load prepared before HTML file.

Hope it will help